# How to parse Json in kotlin-native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I have installed kotlin-native through the following command.

```
brew cask install kotlin-native
```

I am writing a kotlin file and want to parse Json. Json parsing is supported through

```
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*
```

When I try to run the kotlin file (which has the required import) through the following command

```
kotlinc-native hello.kt
```

it throws the following error

```
/Users/anshul/hello.kt:1:16: error: unresolved reference: serialization
import kotlinx.serialization.*
```

How to do json parsing in kotlin native?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to use `kotlinx.serialization` library that is not included in the Kotlin/Native standard library. It is being published separately and so should be downloaded by yourself.
But, I am not sure that this approach can be used widely. The most popular scenario assumes that you will use the Gradle instead of the compiler's CLI interface. If so, library management can be left to the Gradle, requiring only to set up the script correctly. A step-by-step explanation of it can be found in the [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score -1):

Using Intellij IDEA and gradle, you shoud setup kotlinx.serialization plugin

Look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/serialization.html

You can easily create a parser based on JSONjava src code (https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) as I did

If you want a light weight implementation of JSON parser, check it out:
https://github.com/carlosrafp/Kotlin-Native---Simple-JSON